# Adding event listener to a newly added DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom

How do you call an ID that was created through js using a function, but wasn't part of the initial html

```
var topic1 = document.createElement("div")
document.body.appendChild(topic1)
```

we tried using an eventlistener

```
var ff15 = document.getElementById("topic1")
if(ff15){
    ff15.addEventListener("click", response1)
}
```

but it does not work.

Comment: You create simple `<div>` without ID, but try to listen for `#topic1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable `topic1` directly to bind an event listener to it. You don't have to get to that element again using `document.getElementById`.

It could be something as follows:

```js
var topic1 = document.createElement("div");
topic1.innerText = "Some text";
document.body.appendChild(topic1);

topic1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` to the `div` if you want to use `getElementById`.

```
const topic1 = document.createElement('div');
topic1.id = 'topic1';
document.body.appendChild(topic1);

const item = document.getElementById('topic1');
item.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('what');
});
```

But you can just use `topic1` directly if you're not doing anything else.

```
topic1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('what');
});
```